# Highcharts: series does not update if previous array only had null values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an Highchart which updates the series. In some cases (like the fiddle shows), the update does not work correctly.

When the series had an array which only had null-values, the next given array does not take effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCross82/ubz3o4pr/

```
  <body>
  <button onclick="firstData()">1st Data</button>
  <button onclick="secondData()">2nd Data</button>
  <button onclick="firstData()">Again 1st Data (without Series1)</button>

  <div id="chart1" style="height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

var chart1;

chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  series: [{
    data: [],
  },{
    data: [],
  }]
});


function firstData() {
  var series1 = [65.4, 72.7, 70, 60.6, 42.9];
  var series2 = [26, 33, 10, 33, 7];
  updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function secondData() {
  var series1 = [null, null, null, null, null];
  var series2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function updateChart(series1, series2){
  chart1.update({
    series: [{
      data: series1
    },{
        data: series2,
    }]
  });
 }
```

For now, I check the array, and if every value in the array is null, I set the array to []. After this, the update works. But I think this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem looks like a bug, so I reported it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9290

It is worth noting that only update with the same number of data causes the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8nbdy9wq/

To workaround, you can update the chart with `null` values as `y` property:

```
function secondData() {
    var series1 = [{
        y: null
    }, {
        y: null
    }, {
        y: null
    }, {
        y: null
    }, {
        y: null
    }];

    var series2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    updateChart(series1, series2);
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cnw4vh65/